# do not show keyboard in appium test on IOS

Tags: ios-simulator, appium, appium-ios

How can i make appium use physical keyboard instead of soft keyboard?

when running a code with xcode no keyboard is shown at all, but with appium the soft keyboard is shown.

i found `driver.hideKeyboard()` and [Dismissing keyboard in appium test on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25157915/dismissing-keyboard-in-appium-test-on-ios), but they are about how temporary hide keyboard.

The other solution was [using `Command + K`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25938860/iphone-6-simulator-hide-keyboard-issue) which do the trick, but appium does not do that automatically and if you do that manually when appium starts simulator, test will fail!!

Comment: If you want to disable the keyboard from showing up every time you perform an action on a TextView, there's got to be changes in the app code made for this. If you instead want the keyboard not to be used, you can `driver.hideKeyboard()` and use `sendKeys(<yourText>)`

Answer (score 1):

Try the solution as mentioned here by me:
[Toggle Software Keyboard for entire test suite in appium python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43396253/toggle-software-keyboard-for-entire-test-suite-in-appium-python)

[image]

Comment: already tried that, when appium opens the simulator the keyboard come back, likely it kind of reset the simulator (not factory reset since the apps exist)

Comment: does the 'Connect Hardware Keyboard' option stays selected when appium opens the simulator?

Answer (score 0):

You can use sendKeys directly to your desired field. it is independent of keyboard. So i think it will work for you. Example code is below

```
public void usingSendKey(By by, String text){
        WebElement element = null;
        element = driver.findElement(by);
        try{
            element.clear();
        }
        catch(Exception e){

        }
        element.click();
        element.sendKeys(text);
    }
```

Comment: sendKeys work without any problem. it can even send unicode characters, but that is not the problem; i dont want the keyboard to show up, just like when running code with xcode.