# Toggle Software Keyboard for entire test suite in appium python

Tags: automated-tests, ios-simulator, appium, appium-ios, python-appium

Currently I am writing `iOS` tests using Python Appium and would like to completely hide the software keyboard which pops up whenever you have to type something. I am already aware of `driver.hide_keyboard()` function but it's a pain to include it everywhere in tests.

I was going over the [Appium Desired Capabilites](https://appium.io/slate/en/master/?python#appium-server-capabilities) but couldn't find anything that will disable the software keyboard. Appreciate if anyone can help me here?

Answer (score 1):

To disable soft keyboard in iOS simulator do this:

Simulator Menu > Hardware > Keyboard > Connect Hardware Keyboard (enable it)

Even if you quit and reopen the simulator, the selection will stay. I'm not sure what happens when you factory reset the simulator.

screenshots attached.[image]